kubernetes cluster accessing nodes outside of the cluster
I am trying to move all developed applications mainly spark application to kubernetes.
I have a node with address of 172.22.0.80 acting as a master node of kubernetes cluster.
There is a sql server database on another node in the network with the address 172.22.0.60:53817. I can connect to the SQL server through pure nodes when kubernetes doesnt involve
I initialized the kubernetes using below
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.240.0.0/16 --cri-socket=unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock
root@master-node:~# kubectl get all -n  default
NAME                                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/spark-connect-server-0570229314e78d99-exec-1   1/1     Running   0          47s

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   2m1s

I can connect to sql server on node 172.22.0.60 (running at port 53817) but I can't do that from the inside of the pod
root@master-node:~# curl -v telnet://172.22.0.60:53817
*   Trying 172.22.0.60:53817...
* Connected to 172.22.0.60 (172.22.0.60) port 53817 (#0)



root@master-node:~# curl -v telnet://172.22.0.60:53817
*   Trying 172.22.0.60:53817...
* Connected to 172.22.0.60 (172.22.0.60) port 53817 (#0)
^C
#ssh to pod
root@master-node:~# kubectl get pod -n default
NAME                                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
spark-connect-server-0570229314e78d99-exec-1   1/1     Running   0          5m50s
root@master-node:~# POD_NAME=spark-connect-server-0570229314e78d99-exec-1
root@master-node:~# kubectl exec --stdin --tty $POD_NAME -- /bin/sh
sh-5.2# curl -v telnet://172.22.0.60:53817
*   Trying 172.22.0.60:53817...

Can someone suggest me how to resolve above connectivity issue?

I am positing the answer here
The below yaml was something working for me till now and I could curl from the inside of the pod to the outside sql sever node
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: sql-server
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 172.22.0.60
    ports:
      - port: 53817
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sql-server
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 53817
      targetPort: 53817
  externalIPs:
    - 172.22.0.60


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
